# Convert raster to polygon based on cell value ranges using ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, polygon

I have a floating point-valued raster which I need to convert to polygon as follows

Put the cells with VALUE < 0.5 into (a small/the smallest number of) polygons

Cells in the range [0.5, 1] into polygons

and so on..

I looked at the [Raster to Polygon](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001200000008000000) tool, but there is no place to specify range values.
Is there a tool in ArcGIS Desktop/Toolbox for doing this?

Comment: You can create your polygons from your Raster to Polygon output. Make a selection by attributes then copy the select features to a new feature class.

Comment: @evv_gis This is a good approach too but the raster-to-vector conversion is a much more computationally expensive operation than the selection. So if it is a massive raster with numerous complicated polygons you'll be wasting a lot of effort vectorizing them only to subsequently remove them from the vector.

Comment: I honestly misread the post - I thought the OP said they had used the tool already.

Comment: @evv_gis I do that all the time too ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use either the **Con** or **Reclassify** tools to create a new raster with the value range that you are interested in and then perform the raster-to-vector conversion on this newly created raster. Two steps and you're done!

Comment: This is more efficient than the evv_gis approach. Any reason not to use reclass and create a binary raster then polygonize this?

Comment: @usertwoseventwothreenine In my initial comment (now deleted) I suggested using either Reclass or Con, but given it's just a Boolean raster being created, Con really will fit the bill nicely. Reclass is better suited to more complex operations in my opinion. Of course both will do though.

Comment: Funny I think the other way. Reclass simple operationss and Con more difficult. Would be good to have a poll. I wonder which one of us in non-traditional or if it would be close to 50/50?

Comment: @usertwoseventwothreenine That sounds like an interesting question to post! When to use a Conditional Evaluation tool versus a Reclassification tool? You should do it. In light of your view on things, I'll edit my answer to include Con/Reclass.